# Unable to install PMD in Spring tool suite

Tags: pmd, spring-tool-suite

I am unable to install PMD plug-in for STS (build on top of Luna).
Could someone please give the steps to do it?

Comment: I am not sure whether I have to do it through "eclipse market place" or "install new software". Eclipse market place shows two options: 1.eclipse-pmd 1.4 and 2.PMD Eclipse. which is the right one? When I tried with "Install new software" option with "PMD - http://pmd.sf.net/eclipse" it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/ and install for Eclipse 4.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of eclipse-pmd, one of the two PMD plugins you mentioned in your question. If your installing the plugin through the Eclipse Marketplace then you're doing everything right. Once the installation is finished the [getting started guide](http://acanda.github.io/eclipse-pmd/getting-started.html) will help you with setting up eclipse-pmd.

<s>You are, however, not the first who has a problem getting eclipse-pmd 1.4 to work with the Spring Tool Suite. Unfortunately we have not yet found the cause of the problem and are still looking for a solution. If you'd like to help or would like to follow the issue's progress then head over to the [eclipse-pmd issue tracker](https://github.com/acanda/eclipse-pmd/issues/21) at Github.</s>
Update: the issue has been fixed and it had nothing to do with STS.

If your problem is something different then I need more information on what exactly does not work, e.g. does the installation give you an error message or doesthe installation work and you get an error message when running PMD?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps to install PMD in STS.

Download PMD from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd-eclipse/files/ & Extract it.

Copy net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse_1.8.0 folder into ..\sts-bundle\sts-3.9.6.RELEASE\plugins\

then Install eclipse PMD from Eclipse Market Place you will find in Help this option.

Restart your STS.